# Setting cookies in Django

Tags: python, django, cookies

I am new to Django, i have written a simple code for setting referer values in cookies.
Can anyone let me know if i can improve this code by minimizing code lines

```
if (not request.COOKIES.has_key('cookie_url') or not  
        request.COOKIES.has_key('cookie_domain'):
    referer = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    if referer:
        referer_split = re.sub('^(https?:\/\/)', '', referer).split('/')
        if not request.COOKIES.has_key('cookie_url'):
            response_to_user.set_cookie('cookie_url', referer)
        if not request.COOKIES.has_key('cookie_domain'):
            response_to_user.set_cookie('cookie_domain', referer_split[0] )
```

Any help will be appericiated

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Note though that `foo.has_key('bar')` should be spelled `'bar' in foo` throughout. And I suspect your `or` in the opening if statement should be `and`.

Comment: actually requirement is to have 'or' not 'and'